# Instagram real-time API limit of subscriptions

Tags: real-time, instagram-api

What is **maximum number of subscriptions** for the **Instagram's real-time API** ?

Talking about a server that handle customs users and register them for a specific Instagram's real-time API subscription.

For a large scale number of users, would it be viable ?

During my quest of searching some informations about it, Some people talked about **30 subscriptions maximum**...But **nothing official**.

I just wanted to know more about this limit and if someone can point me out the official documentation that point this out.

Thank you in advance !